# how to center align vertically within slider

Tags: materialize

Has anyone figured out how to center align vertically content within a slider (caption and such)?
I've attempted to use the valign-wrapper and valign as designated but it doesn't do anything.
I've also attempted some of the other css tricks for center aligning vertically but nothing seems to work.

HTML Slider:

```
<div class="slider valign-wrapper">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="valign caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="valign caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="valign caption right-align">
          <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="valign caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your current code so we can help you better?

Comment: Its exactly same as materializecss site code. I'll add it for you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
.slider .slides li .caption {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)!important;}
```

I need to point out after reading your question again, this css will vertically align the caption box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change HTML as follows:

```
<li class="valign-wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="valign caption center-align">
    <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
  </div>
</li>
```

And add CSS:

```
.slider .slides li .caption {
    position:relative;
    top: unset;
}
```

This worked for me but I have not tested it on different browsers. Looking good on Firefox though.

Answer (score 0):

Below will align center of your the elements

```
    <li>
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="center-align">
        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
```